# Mysql insert data from few tables using event

Tags: mysql, events, select

I have code:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
delimiter |
CREATE EVENT `ex_test` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE

DO BEGIN
        INSERT INTO exchange_value(first_coin, second_coin, price, volume, `exchange`)
        SELECT first_coin, second_coin, AVG(price), AVG(volume), `exchange`
        FROM (
                SELECT first_coin, second_coin, price, volume, 'bibox' AS 'exchange'
                FROM exchange_bibox 
                UNION ALL
                SELECT first_coin, second_coin, price, volume, 'binance' AS 'exchange'
                FROM exchange_binance
        ) AS subquery;

END |

delimiter ;
```

This code save only one record. When I added `GROUP BY first_coin` query save few records, but not all data, because the records are grouping. How I can save all records? I can't use `group by` and `join`.
Input data are all records from each column from the `exchange_...` tables, while the output data should be combined into one of the input data.

Comment: Define “all data.” What’s the input, what’s the expected output etc

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Hello, I edit my post.

Comment: Doesn't clarify it at all. Easier if you actually show the data and how it should be combined. As in actual rows from a table.